# C- Performing mathematical operations on string characters

Tags: c

I'm confused about mathematical operations being performed on characters in C. This is for implementing a basic cypher. I'm working with a string stored in a command line argument, argv.

```
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(p), m = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
{
    if ((p[i] >= 'A' && p[i] <= 'Z') || (p[i] >= 'a' && p[i] <= 'z'))
    {
        if (argv[1][i % m] >= 'A' && argv[1][i % m] <= 'Z')
        {
            printf("%c", ((p[i] - 'A') + ((argv[1][i % m]) - 'A')) % 26);
        }

        else if (argv[1][i % m] >= 'a' && argv[1][i % m] <= 'z')
        {
            printf("%c", ((p[i] - 'a') + ((argv[1][i % m]) - 'a')) % 26);
        }
    }

    else 
    {
        printf("%c", p[i]);
    }
```

My confusion comes in the "printf" lines. They aren't printing as written, and I don't know why. I did a few tests and found that my code will print fine if I remove the - 'a' and the % 26, to where it just looks like:

```
printf("%c", p[i] + argv[1][i % m]);
```

I don't know why this is, however. In my eyes, what I'm trying to do should be no different than an example given by the prof.:

```
string s = get_string();
if (s != NULL)
{
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z')
    {
        printf("%c", s[i] - ('a' - 'A'));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    }
}
```

In particular, the line:

```
printf("%c", s[i] - ('a' - 'A'));
```

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Characters are - surprise! - _numbers_ you can do regular math with.

Comment: Refer to this page to check your index: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @dan04 Sorry, I realize I didn't make it clear. My code doesn't print the line

`printf("%c", ((p[i] - 'a') + ((argv[1][i % m]) - 'a')) % 26);`

but it does if the line is only

`printf("%c", p[i] + argv[1][i % m]);`

I don't know why this is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
printf("%c", ((p[i] - 'a') + ((argv[1][i % m]) - 'a')) % 26);
```

Stolen from Bathsheba:

> So yes, your expressions of the form (a - b) - (c - b) simplify to a - c.

Well, (a - b) + (c - b) then gets a + c - 2*b, too...

So you get first:

```
printf("%c", (p[i] + argv[1][i % m] - 2*'a') % 26);
//                                           ^  yet left...
```

Next point is % 26 - it will calculate values from 0 to 26 - which all are control characters you presumably do not want to see...

Be aware that 'a' has a numerical value of 97 and 'A' of 65 (in ASCII, at least...). So you'll be interested in re-adding this value to your result:

```
printf("%c", (p[i] + argv[1][i % m] - 2*'a') % 26 + 'a');
//                                                ^ (or 'A' in the upper case case)
```

Comment: He should have seen my ascii table reference page. In there he will see that if he minus by 97, especially when dealing with character 'a', he will definitely get a NUL character.

Comment: I've been using an ASCII reference while writing this code. I've modified the code a bit, but the problem still stands: `printf("%c", (p[i] + ((p[i] - 'a') + ((argv[1][i % m]) - 'a'))) % 26);`

My logic is as follows: take the plaintext character `p[i]`, let's say "b", and subtract a which = (98 - 97) = 1. Take the first cypher character from `argv` (the modulo is so it loops), let's say "c", and subtract a (99 - 97) = 2. Add them, and do modulo 26 so it will wrap around if need be. Then add this to `p[i]` and print to get the cyphertext character. However, it's not printing anything.

Comment: @Davigor Ah, sorry, got irritated from Bathsheba's subtraction - as you are *adding* the differences, calculation looks a little different. Sorry for being inattendant... Fixed the response now. The clue remains the same, though: You still have to add 'a' (or 'A') after the modulo operation! Subtracting `2*'a'` is more efficient, by the way, as the multiplication is done at compile time and you are just subtracting a constant...

Comment: @Davigor Your own variant (using the two differences) must look like this: `printf("%c", ((p[i] - 'a') + (argv[1][i % m] - 'a')) % 26 + 'a');` (adding 'a' *after* the modulo calculation!).

Comment: @Aconcagua Right, I carefully checked through the math again and came to the same conclusion. Adding back in the 'a' gives me what I need. My concern was that I thought it was a syntax problem, or a misunderstanding of how characters behave as integers in C. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, you can simplify your code.

In C, things like `'a'` are `int` types. (Contrary to popular belief, they are **not** `char` types, it's just that the C standard guarantees that they can be assigned to a `char` type without any danger of overflow.) The single quotation notation is used to obviate the fact that C does not mandate a specific character *encoding*. That is, you ought not care what number `'a'` etc. represents. If you do care then strictly speaking your code is not portable C.

So yes, your expressions of the form `(a - b) - (c - b)` simplify to `a - c`.

Comment: Characters are `int`s?! OMG, this is why `strchr`'s second argument is an integer! Now, why do we need `char` and, especially, `char *` to represent strings if we could've used `int *` everywhere?

Comment: Cuz pointer arithmetic on `int*` is platform specific and the C standard specifies sizeof(char) to be 1. Funnily enough, I answered a question on this yesterday. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621142/why-does-this-printf-statement-output-0/43621502#43621530

Comment: this is the problem, to my mind: what if I'm using some Unicode characters and try to put them into an array of `char`s? Can't they be too large to be put into a `char` to get out of `char`'s bounds and thus be truncated violently?

Comment: You can't easily stuff UTF-16 into a char array. You need a wide character type to do that. Lots of stuff on the internet on this.

Comment: @ForceBru Be aware that character *literals* are of type int (i. e. when you write 'a', 'b', '7', ...)! (By the way: different in C++...) If you write `char c;` then c is of type char occupying one single byte (compared to 4 of int on most modern systems).

Comment: @ForceBru "unicode characters and try to [...]" - this is where utf-8 comes into play - unicode code points above 127 need to be distributed over multiple bytes.

Comment: @Aconcagua, right, this makes me wonder why even use `char` for strings, if we could've used `int`s instead to be able to work with Unicode and stuff that goes beyond ASCII?.. And all these fancy wide characters could safely go to hell.

Comment: @Aconcagua, yeah, but why deal with such a nightmare if I could've put a Unicode character into one single `int`?

Comment: @ForceBru: you might not be able to, if `int` is a 1's complement 16 bit. I'd be inclined to stuff the data into what essentially boils down to an `unsigned char` array.

Comment: @ForceBru One could (assuming 4 byte integers - and one would use the unsigned variant then) - but that would blow up the vast majority of text documents by factor of four, as most get along quite well with ASCII only. In most other languages, only few characters need to be encoded with two bytes, e. g. in German äöüßÄÖÜ, Spanish ñ¿¡ (and others).

Comment: @Aconcagua, I completely forgot that the size of text data actually matters XD Well, given the modern bazillion TB drives that may not be a huge problem, although I wouldn't enjoy it if I suddenly needed 4 times as much storage as I have now.

Comment: @ForceBru: While *storage* may be cheap, RAM and network bandwidth are not as cheap.  Plus, there's the issue of backwards compatibility with APIs and protocols that expect text strings to consist of 8-bit code units.  Thus, UTF-8 remains a more popular encoding than UTF-32.